# How to highlight neighbouring nodes in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js and would like to add the feature on mouseover or tap of a node to apply a style to:

1. change the style of the neighbouring nodes - 1st degree
2. fade out the nodes that are not connected

I seem to be able to get the neighbours, any ideas how I apply a style to non neighbours?

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(e) {
                var node = e.cyTarget;
                var directlyConnected = node.neighborhood();
                directlyConnected.nodes().addClass('connectednodes');

            });
```

Answer (score 20):

If ever you haven't found the solution to highlight children of a node when mouse hover one, here is my attempt and it works nice:

Event handler:

```
cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(e){
    var sel = e.target;
    cy.elements().difference(sel.outgoers()).not(sel).addClass('semitransp');
    sel.addClass('highlight').outgoers().addClass('highlight');
});
cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(e){
    var sel = e.target;
    cy.elements().removeClass('semitransp');
    sel.removeClass('highlight').outgoers().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Basically, all elements are filtered if they're not the hovered node or its direct children ("outgoers") and the class 'semitransp' is added to them.
Then, the class 'highlight' is added to the hovered node and all its children.

Example of style for 'highlight' and 'semitransp' class:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    elements: [ {...} ]
    style: [
        {...},
        {
            selector: 'node.highlight',
            style: {
                'border-color': '#FFF',
                'border-width': '2px'
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'node.semitransp',
            style:{ 'opacity': '0.5' }
        },
        {
            selector: 'edge.highlight',
            style: { 'mid-target-arrow-color': '#FFF' }
        },
        {
            selector: 'edge.semitransp',
            style:{ 'opacity': '0.2' }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It should be remembered to add style sheet of the class to the cy object, otherwise addClass doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of cytoscape was this? I don't see the cyTarget property anymore and difference doesn't seem to be doing what is expected.

Comment: @Josiah Try just `e.target`

Comment: cy.elements() is not a function

Answer (score 10):

Addition to Polosson's answer since I am not aloud to comment:

The api seems to have changed, it's **target** instead of **cyTarget** now (Verison 3.2.17).

Also, you might have to add the **incomers** to highlight all neighbours:

```
cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(e) {
    var sel = e.target;
    cy.elements()
        .difference(sel.outgoers()
            .union(sel.incomers()))
        .not(sel)
        .addClass('semitransp');
    sel.addClass('highlight')
        .outgoers()
        .union(sel.incomers())
        .addClass('highlight');
});
cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(e) {
    var sel = e.target;
    cy.elements()
        .removeClass('semitransp');
    sel.removeClass('highlight')
        .outgoers()
        .union(sel.incomers())
        .removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the set difference: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/building--filtering/eles.difference

`cy.elements().difference( dontIncludeTheseEles )`

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply.  How would this be used with a mouseover to show only the connected nodes to an individual node?

Comment: I have also tried eles.neighborhood() and still no success. I have looked through all of the examples on js.cytoscape.com, gists, codepens, etc. Has anyone successfully implemented onhover capabilities to highlight nodes? Perhaps this is a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

This code implements the **click functionality** instead of hover to highlight the node. It´s an extension of Polosson answer.

```html
var previous_node;
var previous_sel;
cy.on("click","node",(e)=>
{
    var sel = e.target;
    var id = e.target.id();

    if ((id != previous_node) && (previous_node != undefined ) && (previous_sel != undefined))
        
    {

        cy.elements().removeClass("semitransp");
        previous_sel.removeClass("highlight").outgoers().union(previous_sel.incomers()).removeClass("highlight");

        cy.elements().difference(sel.outgoers().union(sel.incomers())).not(sel).addClass("semitransp");
        sel.addClass("highlight").outgoers().union(sel.incomers()).addClass("highlight");

        previous_sel = sel;
        previous_node = id;

    }

    else
    
    {
        
        cy.elements().difference(sel.outgoers().union(sel.incomers())).not(sel).addClass("semitransp");
        sel.addClass("highlight").outgoers().union(sel.incomers()).addClass("highlight");
        previous_sel = sel;
        previous_node = id;

    }



    

})
```